# Limit the amount of main pages

Tags: pages, homepage

Hay, i have a site which has been designed to only have 8 main pages across the main navigation, however these pages can have as many subpages as they want. Is there a way to limit the amount of main pages an admin can create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won't it make more sense to limit number of pages that navigation displays? There are many instances when page is not wanted in navigation but still needed somewhere (I have privacy policy set up this way at my blog for example).

Comment: There are plugins to hide pages from the navigation. But the easiest way to keep control of the menus is to use WP3.0's Navigation Menus feature. Not all themes support it, though.